# How do I run AJAX scripts locally on my machine using IIS(or any related technology)?

Tags: ajax, iis, hosting, serverside-javascript

I want to run a few AJAX applications on my laptop, but not sure how to do it using IIS. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really dont even require IIS server setup to run your own AJAX application.

You can take a look at few of the tutorials onlike which talk about creating your own application using HTML.

Tutorial - http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Hello_World-.html

This way you can load HTML pages using AJAX.